# PHP MYSQLI count users with two consecutive dates

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

How can I count users with two consecutive absences only? I have to create a chart to show frequency absences by employee.

My table name = incidencias

```
id | name | dateA     | description
1  | al   |2017-08-01| absence
2  | al   |2017-08-02| absence
3  | alex |2017-08-01| absence
4  | alex |2017-08-02| absence
5  | alex |2017-08-03| absence
6  | al2  |2017-08-01| absence
7  | al2  |2017-08-02| absence
```

I want the result to be 2, only al and al2 have two consecutive dates where description = absence.

I´m using php to run the query, i did try this code i found but and I tested it in sqlfiddle and works great,. but not in my host.I think this is for PostgreSQL.

```
$query2 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT name,
                sum(diff) as days, 
                (dateA) as work_start, 
                (dateA) as work_end 
            FROM (SELECT name,
                    dateA, 
                    diff 
            FROM (select name, 
                    dateA,
                    nvl(dateA- lag(dateA) over (partition by name order by dateA),1) as diff 
            from incidencias 
            where description = 'absence'
            ) t1 
            where diff = 1 
            ) t2 
            group by name
            having sum(diff) = 2");

$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($query2);

printf("Result set has %d rows.\n", $row_cnt);
```

I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Can you please post some sample data on sql format?

Answer (score 1):

So, this is normally done through `JOIN`ing on to the same table.

```sql
SELECT oinc.* 
FROM incidencias oinc
LEFT JOIN 
     incidencias iinc
     ON (oinc.name = iinc.name AND oinc.description = iinc.description)
WHERE description = 'absence' 
     AND oinc.dateA = DATE_ADD( iinc.dateA, 'INTERVAL 1 DAY');
```

So, line by line:

```sql
SELECT oinc.* -- grab me everything from the oinc table

FROM incidencias oinc -- We're going to call incidencias "oinc" in this query
                      -- "oinc" is now an alias for "incidencias"

LEFT JOIN -- I want a result whether or not the result is duplicated.
          -- (Technically, by including the condition that it not be duplicated
          -- this is the same thing as an "INNER JOIN".)

incidencias iinc -- We're looking at the same table, better call it something else

ON (oinc.name = iinc.name AND oinc.description = iinc.description) 
   -- We're matching the name and the description between the two
   -- aliases of the table (oinc, iicn)

WHERE description = 'absence' -- Should be obvious
    AND oinc.dateA = DATE_ADD( iinc.dateA, 'INTERVAL 1 DAY'); -- the iinc alias
           -- has a date which is one day less than the oinc alias
```

Some side notes:

- I used `left` join so that you can omit the `AND ...` later.
- You should experiment with moving that `AND` query from the `WHERE` into the `ON` clause. Then you can use an `INNER` join. You'll get the same results, but knowing both will help you more later.

Comment: Nice. Incomplete however.

Comment: (And this is an inner join - as EXPLAIN EXTENDED followed by SHOW WARNINGS would demonstrate)

Comment: @Strawberry Thought by suggesting "LEFT JOIN" that I'd give him more options to play with the query later.

Comment: OK. But you didn't actually provide a LEFT JOIN. It might look superficially like a LEFT JOIN, but it's an INNER JOIN. Hence my comment.

Comment: @Strawberry Updated to reflect that this is technically an INNER… still think it better opportunity to play with the query later by leaving it notated as a "LEFT JOIN".

Comment: Cool (it would still give a wrong or, more generously, incomplete answer)

Comment: I changed my table and with my query " SELECT oinc.* 
FROM asistenciaMes AS oinc
LEFT JOIN 
     asistenciaMes AS iinc
     ON (oinc.sso = iinc.sso)
WHERE oinc.fecha = DATE_ADD( iinc.fecha, INTERVAL 6 DAY) " but the result gives non consecutive dates, and i only want consecutive dates. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way (there may be a simpler solution, but this should be fast anyway)...

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM 
     ( SELECT name 
            , MAX(i) i
         FROM 
            ( SELECT x.*
                   , CASE WHEN @prev_name = name THEN 
                       CASE WHEN @prev_date = datea - INTERVAL 1 DAY THEN @i:=@i+1 ELSE @i:=1 END 
                       ELSE @i:=1 END i
                   , @prev_name := name
                   , @prev_date := datea
                FROM my_table x
                   , ( SELECT @prev_name:=null,@prev_date:=null, @i:=1) vars 
               WHERE x.description = 'absence'
               ORDER 
                  BY name
                   , datea
            ) b
        GROUP
           BY name
       HAVING i = 2
     ) p;
```